# How to reuse dev-only code between Cargo tests and examples?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have some code in my project (say `mod test_utils` in `lib.rs`) that I would like to reuse in both tests and examples, but I don't want it to bloat the main library. How can I reuse this code?

Hard requirements:

- `test_utils` not in main library by default

Desirable:

- prefer not to to expose a public `test_utils` feature
- prefer not to complicate `cargo test` command

Comment: `#[path = ".."] mod utils`

Comment: I assume you mean something like `#[path = "../path/to/test_utils.rs"] mod test_utils` in the example code. But the test utils use code in the `crate::`, which can't be imported by a `#[path = "..."] mod`?

Comment: Have you tried it? Path resolution depends on the module tree, not file paths.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. The example doesn't seem to count as part of the crate.

Comment: Ah right, examples. You can probably do something like `#[cfg(test)] mod your_crate_name { pub use crate::*; }` so you can use a single name to refer to imports from your crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only way to do this is via another public `foo_test_utils` crate, which gets used as a dev dependency in `foo`. Obviously polluting crates.io with test utils crates is a bad idea, so don't do this.

This may be viewed as a limitation of Cargo, but another argument is that you simply shouldn't try to share non-publicly-exposed logic between tests and examples.

In my particular case, the reuse would be brittle; there's a good chance I'll want to change the tests in the future without changing the example. My original intent was probably misguided. Therefore I decided to simply duplicate the code.